# Custom NSViewController representedObject doesn't update when view selection changes

Tags: cocoa, binding, nsoutlineview, nstreecontroller

I've got a custom NSViewController that's also an NSOutlineViewDataSource. I also have a window with an NSOutlineView bound to an instance of my view controller as the data source, and the NSOutlineView bound to the view: property of the custom view controller.

The controller fills the outline view fine. However, selections within the view don't automatically update the representedObject property of the controller. The only thing that seems to trigger a change in representedObject is when I call setRepresentedObject: directly... which sort of defeats the purpose.

Any idea why that might be? representedObject *is* supposed to update automatically, right? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question, you are not understanding what `representedObject` is for. The `representedObject` is the model object that represents *all* the data that a view controller is displaying. It is not the current selection of a view showing a collection of content. The `representedObject` for your custom top level view controller would be an `NSArray` or other collection class which contains the set of data you are displaying in your view controller. Changing the `representedObject` for your custom top level view controller should have the effect of swapping out for an entirely new data set if the pattern is being used correctly.

Typically the view controllers for the individual elements in a tabular type view would each have their own `representedObject` and this object would not change. For example if you were using an `NSCollectionView` each element in the view is controlled by an `NSCollectionViewItem` which is a subclass of `NSViewController`. The `representedObject` for each `NSCollectionViewItem` tells it what data to present in its little view.

`NSOutlineView` and its superclass `NSTableView` are different in that their cells are often `NSCells` rather than full fledged `NSViews` unless you choose to use them this way in Mac OS X 10.7 or newer. Even in this case, you don't typically have an `NSViewController` subclass managing each cell. So the view controller `representedObject` pattern is not used at the level of the individual element that the user would select. If what you want is to track the `NSOutlineView`'s selection, there are many `NSTableView` methods that let you do this.